# how to detect an intersection when i hit the ground?

Tags: libgdx

Watch this image example:

[image: see example]
Hi guys, I have a question about "Intersector", what I want is when I click the screen, I get the intersection, then I put a 3d modals on the ground according the intersection point. The problem was I can't get the intersection.

Here is my code

```
public Vector3 getIntersect(int screenX, int screenY) {
    Ray ray = cam.getPickRay(screenX, screenY);
    Vector3 ins = new Vector3();
    for (int i = 0; i < parentModels.size; ++i) {
        final GameObject go = parentModels.get(i);
        Intersector.intersectRayBounds(ray, go.bounds, ins);
    }
    return ins;
}
```

GameObject extends form ModelInstance.

Comment: You are effectively only checking the last model of the array since that is the only result your method returns.

Comment: thks, actually there are only the ground added to the parentModels,
finaly I create Plane base on the ground, and then use Intersector.intersectRayPlane method

`Plane plane = new Plane(new Vector3(0,1,0), Vector3.Zero);
            Vector3 intersection = new Vector3();
            if (Intersector.intersectRayPlane(ray, plane, intersection)) {
                if(box.contains(intersection)){
                    return intersection;
                }
            }  `